# post variable from controller not show in modal in view page codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Hello guys need some help

In my `controller`:

```
public function index() {
 $data['myvar'] = 'hai';
 $this->load->view('Bank/Main',$data);
}
```

In `view`:

```
echo  $myvar ;
```

its works ... i can view my variable

but in another function in same controller

```
public function getdatafromview() {
 $data['myvar']=$this->input->get('keywordid');        --> from post
 $this->load->view('Bank/bankModal',$data);

}
```

in view :

```
echo  $myvar ;
```

It did not work. I cannot view my variable in my view **class="modal"**  ?

```
Message: Undefined variable: myvar

Filename: Bank/Main.php
```

**variable : myvar** from function(getdatafromview) not store in **ci_cached_vars**

Answer (score 0):

Post variables won't be available via `get` only `post`. Further, you should plan for errors such as this and remove the modal entirely when the variable isn't defined via a condition block:

Pseudo code:

```
{if !isset($myvar)} {modal} {/if}
```

Comment: No. Why do you care about the internal variables in CI?

Answer (score 0):

Solved By this method

Post data from view :

```
<td style="width: 100px;">
 <a href="#?keywordid='.$result_tbckat['idbank'].'" class="btn-act edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bankModal"  id="posteidt"><span data-original-title="Edit" class="lnr lnr-pencil" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="top" title=""></span></a>
</td>
```

step 2 in controller :

```
public function get_datamodal(){

        $komemo=$this->input->get('keywordid');

        $data=$this->M_bank->get_bank_by_kode($komemo);

        echo json_encode($data);
```

step 3 in model :

```
function get_bank_by_kode($komemo){
    $hsl=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM m_bank WHERE idbank='$komemo' order by unikid desc");
    if($hsl->num_rows()>0){
        foreach ($hsl->result() as $data) {
            $hasil=array(
                'idbank'        => $data->idbank,
                'cnamabank'     => $data->cnamabank,
                'cnorekening'   => $data->cnorekening,
                'cstatus'       => $data->cstatus
                );
        }
    }
    return $hasil;
}
```

step 4 in view ui modal :

put under the div element :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#posteidt').click(function(){
var id=$(this).attr('data');

    $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url  : "<?php echo base_url('Bank/get_datamodal?keywordid=xxx')?>",
    dataType : "JSON",
    data : {id:id},
    success: function(data){
    $.each(data,function(idbank,cnamabank){
    $('#bankModal').modal('show');
    $('[name="kdbank"]').val(data.idbank);
    $('[name="nmbank"]').val(data.cnamabank);
    //console.log(data);
    });
    }
    });

    // return false;


});
});
</script>
```